# Как сделать пакетное обновление без использования BulkUpdate Платной библиотеки Z.EntityFramework.Extensions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-4.8

Как можно сделать пакетное обновление не используя BulkUpdate.
https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-update

```
list.ForEach(x=>
{x.price=100;
x.quality="Good";
});
```

Есть список в котором уже находиться обновлённая таблица
но там применяется `db.Table.BulkUpdate(list)`, а это платная библиотека, есть ли другой способ сделать пакетное обновление, чтоб оно еще быстро работало?

Comment: .NetFramework 4.8 EF 6.0

Comment: [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) - список расширений для EF **Core**. По крайней мере некоторые из них работают в .NET Standard, а значит можно использовать в .NET FW. | Ищите на странице по термину "bulk" - находится 4 библиотеки. Я бы советовал [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). А ещё лучше - взять [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) ORM. Но не уверен, насколько хороша у них поддержка устаревшего .NET FW.

Comment: Самым простым и быстрым решением будет использовать сырые sql-запросы: [Sending raw commands to the database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql#sending-raw-commands-to-the-database)